# Jenkins how to use jenkins variables in sshCommand plug-in?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm building war file by using maven and sending this build to another server via Jenkins ssh Publisher plugin.

```js
        stage('Deploy develop build to Test Server') {
            when {
                branch 'develop'
            }
            steps {
                // sends war file to test_server
                dir("${WORKSPACE}/ag.mycompany.feature/target/") {
                    sshPublisher(
                        alwaysPublishFromMaster: true,
                        continueOnError: false,
                        failOnError: true,
                        publishers: [
                            sshPublisherDesc(
                                configName: "test_server",
                                transfers: [sshTransfer(sourceFiles: "vc-admin_${VERSION}_${BUILD_NUMBER}_dev.war", remoteDirectory: '/wars/main_vc_admin/develop')],
                                verbose: true
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

this part working very well, I can see my war file with version and build number

then, I'm trying to cp these files (in remote server) to another folder and build a docker image via docker-compose.

connection to remote server via withCredentials is OK, and I tested with some sudo command like 'docker ps' and working well.

but I can't pass variables like VERSION and BUILD_NUMBER to sshCommand
is there any way to pass these variables?

And all examples in internet that I saw are in script{ ... } block for withCredentials and sshPublisher, that's why I used script block in declerative pipeline. I don't know how to create remote variable by using declerative pipeline.

```js
        stage("build docker containers") {
           when {
              branch 'develop'
           }
           steps {
              script{                                                             
                 withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'test_server', 
                    keyFileVariable: 'test_user', 
                    passphraseVariable: '', 
                    usernameVariable: 'test_user')]) {
                    
                    // code block
                    def remote = [ : ]
                    remote.name = "MY_TEST_SERVER"
                    remote.host = "1.1.1.1"
                    remote.user = "user"
                    remote.password = "pass"
                    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                    remote.identityFile = test_user
                    remote.pty = true

                    sshCommand remote: remote, command="cp /home/user/wars/main_vc_admin/develop/vc-admin_${VERSION}_${BUILD_NUMBER}_dev.war /home/user/main-vc-deployment/backend/vc-admin.war"
                    sshCommand remote: remote, sudo: true, command: "docker-compose --file /home/user/main-vc-deployment build && docker-compose --file /home/user/main-vc-deployment run -d"
    
         }                     
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `name="..."` does not look correct for a named parameter of a step, have you tried `command: "..."`?

Comment: @criztovyl yes you are right, the right syntax for sshCommand is
`command: "..."` not `=`
and for jenkins variables again correct syntax is `${BUILD_NUMBER}` without single quatation mark.